# What mammals can rotate and move their ears the most?

Tags: zoology, muscles, hearing, movement

I found out that rabbits can rotate their ears 270 degrees, and also move them up, down and independently. Are there any other mammals that can control their ears' position that well, or even better?

Comment: Can't find a study with actual measurements, but from personal experience horses can move their ears through a pretty wide range: tilting about 180 degrees forward & back, and rotating independently about the same angle.